# Efficient binary patcher

Tags: file, delphi

I am currently working on a little binary patcher. My current code works fine but I do want my code to be optimized (fast) and as clean as possible. Could you all please help me review this?

IDE: Delphi 7 and XE7

```
const
  OriginalByte: array [0 .. 55] of Byte = ($64, $69, $6E, $67, $20, $6D, $65,
    $20, $68, $69, $73, $00, $00, $00, $00, $27, $00, $00, $28, $00, $00, $00,
    $21, $00, $00, $00, $63, $6F, $6D, $70, $75, $74, $65, $72, $2E, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $27, $00, $00, $28,
    $00, $00, $00, $00);

  BytetoWrite: array [0 .. 55] of Byte = ($63, $68, $6F, $67, $20, $6D, $65,
    $20, $68, $69, $73, $00, $00, $00, $00, $27, $00, $00, $28, $00, $00, $00,
    $21, $00, $00, $00, $63, $6F, $6D, $70, $75, $74, $65, $72, $2E, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $27, $00, $00, $28,
    $00, $00, $00, $06);

function CompareByteArrays(FirstArray, SecondArray: array of Byte): Boolean;

var
  Counter: Integer;
begin

  Result := True;
  if Length(FirstArray) <> Length(SecondArray) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  for Counter := Low(FirstArray) to High(FirstArray) do

  begin
    if (FirstArray[Counter]) <> (SecondArray[Counter]) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end

  end;

end;

procedure DoMyPatch();
var

  i: Integer;
  FileName: string;
  input: TFileStream;

  FileByteArray, ExtractedByteArray: array of Byte;

begin
  FileName := 'Cute1.res';

  try
    input := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
      Exit;
    end
  end;

  input.Position := 0;
  SetLength(FileByteArray, input.size);
  input.Read(FileByteArray[0], Length(FileByteArray));
  for i := Low(FileByteArray) to High(FileByteArray) do
  begin

    ExtractedByteArray := Copy(FileByteArray, i, Length(OriginalByte));

    if CompareByteArrays(ExtractedByteArray, OriginalByte) = True then
    begin
      // Begin Patch
      input.Free;
      try
        Win32Check(CopyFile(PChar(FileName), PChar(ChangeFileExt(FileName,
          '.BAK')), False));
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage(E.Message);
          Exit;
        end
      end;

      try
        input := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage(E.Message);
          Exit;
        end
      end;

      input.Seek(i, SoFromBeginning);

      input.Write(BytetoWrite[0], Length(BytetoWrite));

      ShowMessage('Patch Success');
      input.Free;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage('Patch Fail');

  input.Free;

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

1. add definition of the undeclared variables `BytetoWrite`, `OriginalByte` and how they are used/initialized
2. format your code for better readability. Left indentation is not aligned. Too many void blank lines
3. using

   ```
   resource := CreateResource;
   try
       // do something
   finally
       FreeAndNil(resource);
   end
   ```

   pattern is easy to follow and it prevents unintended memory leaks nicely
4. for byte-to-byte memory compare in `CompareByteArrays` better use built-in `CompareMem` function instead of custom array traversal. In an old language runtime source codes this function was implemented in optimized assembly language
5. using `Integer` for file-offset is not very future-friendly idea considering that it is normal (for average end-user) today to work with video files in 4K resolution where single file size can be >4GB
6. using Memory Mapped Files for read-only file access will give you simpler code (whole file is an in-memory array) and faster I/O operations (on-demand reading managed by OS kernel code). This method can give you significant boost if the original file is big and the searched-pattern is located near the beginning of the file
7. the loop should end at `High(FileByteArray) - Length(OriginalByte)` (+/-1) as beyond this boundary the pattern can not be found anyway
8. you can get some speed by comparing against the original byte array just offset by the `i` index. Creation of the intermediate `ExtractedByteArray` would not be necessary (throw away, safe some memory allocation and memory copy CPU-clocks). Like this:

   ```
   if CompareByteArrays(ExtractedByteArray, OriginalByte) = True then
   ```

   ```
   if CompareMem(@FileByteArray[i], @OriginalByte[0], Length(OriginalByte)) = True then
   ```

   assuming the `i`...`i + Length(OriginalByte) - 1` boundaries are withing the range `Low(FileByteArray)`...`High(FileByteArray)` as mentioned in **(7)**

Comment: thanks for your comments, and sorry i can't upvote you (not enough reputation) but i do have one question.
if i use  

resource := CreateResource;
try
try
    // do something
except
 raise
 exit;
end
finally
    FreeAndNil(resource);
end

the "finally" segment of the code doesn't get executed because of the "exit" command right?

Comment: @Xor-el `finally` block will execute always (unless your application is crashing irrecoverably or the computer is going out of e-power). See [Stack Overflow: Does the statements in the Finally block still execute in this piece of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611485/does-the-statements-in-the-finally-block-still-execute-in-this-piece-of-code) for some "proof"

Comment: @Xor-el thanks for your accept/vote although it was probably too fast as some better answer may appear once the new year's eve holidays are over. Looking at your code after the edit it seems that the patcher is single-purpose so the **(5)** does not apply. Using **(6)** can give you significant boost if the original file is big and the searched-pattern is located near the beginning of the file. **(7)** the loop should end at `High(FileByteArray) - Length(OriginalByte)` (+/-1) otherwise you'll face the (random) access violation problem if the pattern is not there

Comment: i don't think so because i have tested it with a pattern that does not exist and it works fine (it does not crash) and informs me that pattern was not found (patch fail).

Comment: @Xor-el you're right. I'm not sure about Delphi but FreePascal's `Copy` routine has the buffer overrun protection built in (`if (count>...` in `fpc_dynarray_copy` in http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/inc/dynarr.inc). Also **(8)** you can get some speed by comparing against the original byte array just offset by the `i` index. Creation of the intermediate `ExtractedByteArray` would not be necessary (throw away, safe some memory allocation and memory copy CPU-clocks)

Comment: @xmomjr, could you provide a litle code snippet for the offset method you stated above?

Comment: @xmomjr, i have edited the code with respect to your corrections, except that of (6) because i am limited in knowledge regarding Memory Mapped Files.
Here is my edited version. http://pastebin.com/2StuKtRK could you please review it. thanks.

Comment: @Xor-el this http://pastebin.com/eAcpDpCG is my version of your version showing what I meant. Use code where you know what it does and why. Not someone else's. Regarding the Memory Mapped Files e.g. http://delphi-snippets.blogspot.cz/2006/04/fast-reading-of-files-using-memory.html shows how to use it. There may be better alternatives, I've picked 1st article found by Google that seemed suitable **(9)** moving the code talking with end-user (through `ShowMessage`) out of the internal `DoMyPatch` procedure would be the next thing... **(10)** be consistent in your variable name-casing conventions

Comment: @xmomjr, this code " iMax := High(FileByteArray) - Length(OriginalByte);" makes your code fail to find the pattern even if it exists.

Comment: @Xor-el the loop invariant must be that `i >= Low(FileByteArray)` and `i + Length(OriginalByte) - 1 <= High(FileByteArray)` to keep the memory window within the allocated range. So what should be the correct `iMax` then?  I would have to use debugger to find out :(

Comment: @xmomjr, also is there any disadvantage of having the "showmessage" inside the procedure "DoMyPatch"?

Comment: @Xor-el for me it is just a habit. Having it inside is Ok as long as your application's logic and user interface remain wired together in one simple unit. If you'd want to implement patch of 30 files in a loop and notify the user about the success/failure only once (and not forcing him/her to click 30 times) then it would not be easy to do. I don't know what is a good source for some more background why people actually do the "_GUI from logic separation_" but Martin Fowler used to write books that some people found useful (I did not read them), e.g. http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Comment: @xmomjr, nice habit i must say.

Comment: Yes it is ;) These Wikipedia articles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture can give you some more useful Google keywords